# C# Create GPO in AD

Tags: c#, dns, gpo

I create GPO

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CreateAndLinkGPO(domain, "OU=Company,OU=Users,OU=Users,DC=Company.local,DC=net", "new_test_policy");
    }

    public void CreateAndLinkGPO(string strDomain, string strOU, string strGPOName)
    {
        GPM gpm = new GPMGMTLib.GPM();
        IGPMConstants gpc = gpm.GetConstants();
        IGPMDomain gpd = gpm.GetDomain(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("USERDNSDOMAIN"), "", gpc.UseAnyDC);
        GPMSOM som = gpd.GetSOM(strOU);

        GPMSearchCriteria gps = gpm.CreateSearchCriteria();
        IGPMGPOCollection gpoc = gpd.SearchGPOs(gps);

        IGPMGPO gpo = gpd.CreateGPO();
        gpo.DisplayName = strGPOName;

        som.CreateGPOLink(-1, gpo);
    }
```

and when i'm click button, i have error at line "GPMSOM som = gpd.GetSOM(strOU);"  - "Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007202B"
I'm domain administrator. when I omit the line below, the policy is created, but the error is still displayed.
please help, thank!

Comment: can't you just catch the exception?

Comment: Yes, Google did not help me

Comment: if you meant you **can** catch the exception, catch and debug that spot so see what happen, if you meant you can't catch it read here, i think your argument is invalid - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.grouppolicy.gpdomain.getsom(v=vs.85).aspx